# Why does defining a function in C shows a weird error of putting ')' before a variable

Tags: c

Wen I try to compile my file stack-zero.c with the command `gcc stack-zero.c -o stack0` it show this as error `stack-zero.c:19:17: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘LEVELNAME’`

The code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to " LEVELNAME ", brought to you by https://exploit.education"

char *gets(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct {
    char buffer[64];
    volatile int changeme;
  } locals;

  printf("%s\n", BANNER);

  locals.changeme = 0;
  gets(locals.buffer);

  if (locals.changeme != 0) {
    puts("Well done, the 'changeme' variable has been changed!");
  } else {
    puts(
        "Uh oh, 'changeme' has not yet been changed. Would you like to try "
        "again?");
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Has `LEVELNAME` been defined anywhere? Otherwise the compiler will only see `printf("%s\n", "Welcome to " LEVELNAME ", brought to you by https://exploit.education");` without ever knowing what `LEVELNAME` should mean.

Comment: What is `LEVELNAME ` ? Please take some time to read the [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your question stands now there is insufficient information to be able to help you.

Comment: Note: You (usually) can add definitions for macros via a compiler flag, e.g. GCC uses `-D` for, though for the definition containing quotes and possibly spaces you might need to escape appropriately; with most linux shells using single quotes around might do the trick (one of either `'-DLEVELNAME="hello world"'` or `-DLEVELNAME='"hello world"'`, no shell available to test atm, though).

Comment: Who has told you to use `gets`?  Don`t ever listen to them again. (Unless you've read it in a really old book such as K&R; it's a good book but rather outdated).

Comment: Indeed – `gets` has been removed from the standard since C11 – for a very good reason (one of the rare cases C breaking backwards compatibility – and if C people do, the reason *is* a good one!).

Comment: @Aconcagua Seems like OP is deliberately trying to overflow the buffer with `gets` input - that's how the `changename` member will get modified.

Comment: Syntax errors have a knack for producing confounding error messages, throw in the preprocessor to make them extra hard to understand.  The compiler basically sees `printf("%s\n", "something" asdf);` and has no idea what `asdf` could possibly mean.  It was busy parsing a function call, so suggesting that the ')' is expected is fairly reasonable.

Comment: Have never seen before placing local variables inside a struct. Don't think it's a good idea – or would you want to introduce new structs with every set of variables with more limited scope (local to loops, if/else clauses)? OK, as C, you might get along without doing though (not C++, though – considering RAII and other features), but I think the advantage of variables existing only where needed weighs more than the explicit local scope.

Comment: @AdrianMole Well, actually that can be done with `fgets` as well – just pretend to it the size was larger than the one of the real buffer. This then could – if wanted at all – prevent writing beyond the entire struct at least.

Comment: We currently have two answers (one deleted, for now) assuming missing escape characters and one assuming a missing definition of LEVELNAME. I guess we need some clarity, here.

Answer (score 1):

`LEVELNAME` is not defined. Define it and the problem is gone. Adding `#define LEVELNAME "Ultimate level"` before `BANNER` would compile and yield output as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LEVELNAME "Ultimate level"
#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to " LEVELNAME ", brought to you by https://exploit.education"

char *gets(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct {
    char buffer[64];
    volatile int changeme;
  } locals;

  printf("%s\n", BANNER);

  locals.changeme = 0;
  gets(locals.buffer);

  if (locals.changeme != 0) {
    puts("Well done, the 'changeme' variable has been changed!");
  } else {
    puts(
        "Uh oh, 'changeme' has not yet been changed. Would you like to try "
        "again?");
  }

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: While correct I'm not sure if that's the right place for – possibly the definition is intended to be changed from outside the file (not having to change it), so might be useful to show up the alternatives like including a header containing the definition (which might be generated in a pre-build step) or defining it via command line flags.

Comment: I think the OP wants to display the actual `" LEVELNAME "` in their banner. So, just needs to escape the internal `"` characters.

Comment: thanks I tried this and it worked @Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

In C programming language, the character **"** is considered to be a special character, as it defines the opening and closing of a string.

Try using your BANNER definition like this:

```
#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to \" LEVELNAME \", brought to you by https://exploit.education"
```

Comment: `LEVELNAME` is probably supposed to include the double quotes itself, to make it more readable. However, the question is incomplete and so it's ambiguous.